# In-place quick sort java

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I am to write a quick sort method for java that swaps entries locally, which means there will be no helper array to store things, and swapping is done in-place. So I used some variables to help keep track where the "low" "hi" and "pivot" pointer should be.

When I run the tests, it gives me `Stack Overflow` error. But when I run it on my `main()` with some simple test arrays, e.g. :

```
int[] A = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
```

It gives me the right result.

I guess the bug (presumably an infinite loop) is only triggered by some special cases, but I couldn't find it.

Here are my code.

```
  public static void quicksort( int[] A, int low, int hi ){


  int len = hi - low + 1;


  if (len < 2){   // base case 1
         return;
         }

  else if(len == 2){  // base case 2 (bug-prone now)
      if(A[low]<=A[hi]){
          return;}    
      }



  else{    // start scanning and swapping and recursing
      int pivot = low;    //the index of pivot

      while(len>1){  //  as long as the pivot is not at where it should be...scan and swap

         // pivot = low; // updating...unnecessary?

          while(pivot<hi){             // check on the right
              if (A[pivot]<=A[hi]){
                  hi--;
              }else{
                  break;
              }
          }

          if(A[pivot]>A[hi]){         //now swap pivot and hi;
              int holder=A[pivot];
              A[low]=A[hi];
              A[hi]=holder;

              pivot=hi;              // update pointers
              low++;
          }



          while(pivot>low){             // check on the left
              if (A[pivot]>=A[low]){
                  low++;
              }else{
                  break;
              }
          }

          if(A[pivot]<A[low]){         //now swap pivot and low;
              int holder=A[pivot];
              A[hi]=A[low];
              A[low]=holder;

              pivot=low;
              hi--;                   // update pointers
              }

      len = hi - low + 1;         // update len for the loop check

      }

      // now the pivot is in the right position...split and recurse.
      quicksort(A, 0, pivot-1);    // recurse on the left

      quicksort(A, pivot+1, A.length-1);  // recurse on the right

      } // the end of the else case.
```

}

Comment: actually quicksort IS an in-place algorithm

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the StackOverflow error cannot be caused by just an infinite loop... because it does not consumes memory. Recursive calls do, so I think your problem is your algorithm has too many recursive calls (last two sencences). Try to change the base case to avoid that (for example, using another sort algorithm when length is shorter than 10, or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

It's because your two recursive calls at the end of your method sort the entire array again, rather than just between `low` and `high`. You need to limit your recursive calls to `low` at the bottom end and `high` at the top end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to break your quick sort method into multiple small methods after which the readability  will be increased.

Further, StackOverflow exception means that stack is full and no further method call can be made. See where in your code are you calling methods. I see two places at the end:

```
// now the pivot is in the right position...split and recurse.
quicksort(A, 0, pivot-1);    // recurse on the left

quicksort(A, pivot+1, A.length-1);  // recurse on the right
```

Please debug what is the value it is passing in these functions.

Also, it will be good if you can paste the code for your test case also.